# Xfce: Tab Key No Longer Navigates Within Some Dialog Windows

Tags: xfce, window-manager, gtk2

Xfce 4.10; Gtk 2.24.25

For example, `zenity --question` invokes an austere zenity question dialog window with default verbiage and two buttons, as expected. But, with focus on said window, pressing the **Tab** key does not visually appear to rotary the internal focus (as evidenced by a faint, dashed rectangle) through either of the two buttons.

This just started happening recently and I've been unable to find a solution - any ideas for smarter searches appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an examination of files that had been changed in the last day or so, hoping to find the culprit.

I had inadvertently, when working another issue, changed the appearance style of my desktop.

To solve my issue:

Open the **Xfce Settings Editor**

Select the **xsettings** channel

In the **Property** window, go to the **Net** section

Scrutinize the **ThemeName** property

Mine was set to **Raleigh**

I changed same to **Xfce**

End of problem...

**Addendum:** Apparently, since my system did not have a theme available that was named **Xfce**, the desktop settings reverted to a default style, which is what I originally was rocking before mucking things up.

Any improvements to this "solution" are welcomed...
.

***UPDATE: Xfce 4.12; Gtk 2.24.31***

Experienced a similar problem, "solution" was the same as above...